# How to block days in UIDatePicker for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, datepicker, uipickerview

I'm using a Date picker on my IOS app, and I want to know if is possible to block some days. For example, I need to block all mondays from a year, is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: yep, you just have to use a simple `UIPickerView` with custom datas, easy.

Comment: @holex So I just use a regular UIPickerView and add all the dates or what?

Comment: honestly, yes. exactly. this is the only way to work with custom datas in the `UIPickerView`, you cannot set up the standard `UIDatePicker` with dropping off some unwanted days.

Comment: Yes.  The UIDatePicker just adds in 0-31 for days.  The days that can't be selected turn grey.  If a user selects one of the grayed out days, it just bounces away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing you can do is add a custom UIPickerView as described in the comments or implement a method that is called for the event `UIControlEventValueChanged` as described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html)

then check the new value for a valid weekday. you can get the weekday with:

```
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents* components = [calendar components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
return [components weekday]; // 1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, ...
```

There is no way to hide some days in the scrollwheel.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the **Swift 4** answer to this question (original answer by Nicholas Harlen):

```
let datePicker: UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker(frame: .zero)
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

@objc func datePickerValueChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let calender: Calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    let weekday = calender.component(.weekday, from: sender.date)
    //sunday
    if weekday == 1 {
        datePicker.setDate(Date(timeInterval: 60*60*24*1, since: sender.date), animated: true)
    } else if weekday == 7 {
        datePicker.setDate(Date(timeInterval: 60*60*24*(-1), since: sender.date), animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something similar and couldn't find a way of removing dates.  However what I ended up doing was if an invalid date is selected it would bounce away to the nearest day that was valid, similar to how the control handles if you set a minimum date and try and choose a date before that.

```
-(void)init
{
    datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
    [datePicker setMinimumDate: [NSDate date]];
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(onDatePickerValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

-(void)onDatePickerValueChanged:(UIDatePicker *)picker
{
    // Work out which day of the week is currently selected.
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:picker.date];
    int weekday = [comps weekday];

    // Bounce Sundays (weekday=1) forward a day
    if (weekday == 1)
    {
        [datePicker setDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:60*60*24*1 sinceDate:picker.date] animated: true];
    }
    // Bounce Saturdays (weekday=7) back a day
    else if (weekday == 7)
    {
        [datePicker setDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:60*60*24*-1 sinceDate:picker.date] animated: true];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 16, we have a dedicated calendar view, MultiDatePicker, that lets users select multiple dates.

https://sarunw.com/posts/swiftui-multidatepicker/