# Swift: UIDatePicker without weekends

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I am making a business iOS application. They want to contact user from Monday till Friday. Can I somehow disable showing Weekends in UIDatePicker?

Comment: No.  You either need to create your own picker or use the delegate method to move the picker to the next/previous weekday if the user stops on a weekend day

Comment: you block weekends day.but u cannot disable.if u disable weekends day then you create custom pickerview using UIPickerview.

Comment: Try this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53534470/5325926